# How to simulate database behaviour in PHP?

Tags: php, json, database, parsing

I have a dataset with about 100 entries in JSON format:

```
[
  {"name":"Julia","state":"CA","income":66000},
  {"name":"Peter","state":"NY","income":35000},
  {"name":"Greg","state":"CA","income":0},
  {"name":"Celine","state":"MN","income":27000}
]
```

Since the dataset will not change very often, I'd like to keep the dataset together with the code in one git repo and get rid of the dependency to a database.

Typical queries are `return all entries where the name starts with a G` or `return all entries where the sate equals CA`. One way would be:

- Read the JSON-file using `file_get_contents()`  (

  > It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

  ```
  $data = file_get_contents("data.json");
  ```
- Afterwards I parse the JSON-data to an array:

  ```
  $json = json_decode($data);
  ```
- Finally I iterate through all data to check, if it equals a given value

  ```
  ...
  $json[$i]->{"state"} == "CA";
  ...
  ```

Now I have some **questions**:

- Is the parsing of the JSON string somehow cached, or is it carried out everytime I call `json_decode($data)`.
- Is there a way to directly read the JSON-Data into an own class (by default it is some kind of standard class)?

  ```
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Julia"
    ["state"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["income"]=>
    int(66000)
  }
  ```
- Is there a better way of solving the task [complex objects, not database] (I guess there is,...)

Comment: It won't be cached, but `json_decode` appears to be quite performant. A *million* executions of it on your sample JSON took my laptop three seconds.

Comment: If your json is hand crafted, why not simply create a php array?

Comment: @e4c5: Well, that's only for convenience. I'd like to edit the file In a different editor,...

Comment: well JSON and PHP can both be edited by the same editor and there is little difference between your json file and an equivalent PHP file. And you did say it doesn't change much

Comment: @RyanVincent: You're right,... I did not realized, that SQLite it integrated in PHP. But than it requires an additional step during deployment, doesn't it (i.e. replacing old data with new data). Do you think it's a good idea to keep the JSON in my repository, and during deployment replace previous data with (potentially) new entries?

Comment: OK, it seems that having an array of objects of an own class seems the way to go. Can anyone  write an answer so that I can accept it.